# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ResolutionSevice

Tags: typescript, nestjs

im currently exploring nestjs and came across this error:

> Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ResolutionService (?).
> Please make sure that the argument ResolutionRepository at index [0]
> is available in the ResolutionService context.
>
> Potential solutions:
>
> - If ResolutionRepository is a provider, is it part of the current ResolutionService?
> - If ResolutionRepository is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within ResolutionService?   @Module({
>   imports: [ /* the Module containing ResolutionRepository */ ]   })

What am I doing wrong here?

resolution.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ResolutionEntity } from './resolution.entity';
import { ResolutionService } from './resolution.service';
import { ResolutionRepository } from './resolution.repository';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ResolutionEntity])],
  providers: [ResolutionRepository, ResolutionService],
  exports: [ResolutionService],
})
export class ResolutionModule {}
```

resolution.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ResolutionEntity } from './resolution.entity';
import { ResolutionRepository } from './resolution.repository';

@Injectable()
export class ResolutionService {
  constructor(private readonly resolutionRepository: ResolutionRepository) {}

  async getAllByName(name: string): Promise<ResolutionEntity[]> {
    return this.resolutionRepository.getAllByName(name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `ResolutionService` in an `imports` array somewhere in your application. Providers **never** go in the `imports` array, only in the `providers`. If you need this provider in another module, the `ResolutionModule` should have the `ResolutionService` in the `providers` and `exports` arrays, and then this new module should have `ResolutionModule` in the `imports` array.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ResolutionEntity])
```

Maybe you want

```
TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ResolutionEntity, ResolutionRepository])
```